# Moving PictureBox At Runtime Causes Too Much Lag

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and i am having some difficulties. I have 80 pictureBoxes in my form's panel. When i run my program it causes slow performance. My pictureBoxes at runtime causes lag. I don't why it's happening, maybe because of loads of pictureBoxes i have? Please can someone help me out with this?  I have A Ghost image in pictureBoxe And some images of Food in(Dots) pictureBoxes as well.Here's my code.

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
                GhostPictureBox.Left -= 5;
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                GhostPictureBox.Left += 5;
                break;
            case Keys.Up:
                GhostPictureBox.Top -= 5;
                break;
            case Keys.Down:
                GhostPictureBox.Top += 5;
                break;

        }


    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GhostPictureBox.Left -= 5;

        PictureBox[] Dots = new PictureBox[80];


        for (int i = 0; i < Dots.Length; i++)
        {
            Dots[i] = (PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" + (i + 1).ToString(), true)[0];

            if (GhostPictureBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Dots[i].Bounds))
            {
                Dots[i].Hide();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 80 picture boxes... that remembers me when I started learning VB XD, please, don't do that, games aren't programmed with picture boxes, use DirectDraw, OpenGL, or at least WPF which have hardware acceleration.

Comment: Yeah, too many PictureBoxes.  Get rid of them all and just draw the images in the container's paint event.  WinForm's is better at line of business apps than game-like apps you are trying to create.

Comment: This is very possible with GDI+ but you should only use one picturebox (or just draw on the background).

Comment: Yes, Gusman and LarsTech are both right if you are writing a real game.  I'm guessing the picture boxes will work as is if you are just messing around, but you don't want to write a real game like that.  I did answer the immediate question, though, if you just want to get what you have working.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a PacMan type game?  Looks like you are loading the dots and doing the FindControl for each every time you check one, and all that every tick so that WOULD make it very slow.  Maybe just make the array global once they are created, then you would only have to check the intersection.  But even just loading the dots once before the loop would probably help a lot.   You should really only have to do it once at the beginning of the level, though.

Comment: Well thanks for the suggestion, and yes i am creating a pacman type game.